# How to get notification from sqltabledependency in any network ? How to make it network independent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sqldependency

I have observed that `SqlTableDependency` event gets fired when I am in my  office network but it is not fired in my home network. I have done the following steps:

1. Enable broker
2. Create Queues, services
3. I have subscribed in my C# applications
4. SQL version is also SQL2014

In my C# application I have added following code:

```
//created the new instance 
tableDependency = new SqlTableDependency<User>
                      (mStarterConnectionString, tableName); //subscribed to the events

tableDependency.OnChanged += TableDependency_OnChanged;
tableDependency.OnStatusChanged += 
                      TableDependency_OnStatusChanged;
tableDependency.OnError += TableDependency_OnError;
tableDependency.TraceLevel = 
                      System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Verbose;
tableDependency.TraceListener = new 
                      TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out);
tableDependency.Start();
```

No action happens after executing `WAITFOR` command even if I insert a new record in the table, where `SqlDependencyTest` is the table name.  I am getting an error in my console:

```
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Queue
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a_Receiver created.
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Queue
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a_Sender created.
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Service broker
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a_Sender created.
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Service broker
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a_Receiver created.
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Procedure
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a created. [Server: .
Database: SqlDependencyTest]Conversation with handler
1ef8f17b-dcdf-e811-b097-5ce0c5147b2e started. [Server: . Database:
SqlDependencyTest]Trigger
dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a created. [Server: .
Database: SqlDependencyTest]All OK! Database objects created with
naming dbo_Users_13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a. [Server: .
Database: SqlDependencyTest]Waiting for receiving Users's records
change notifications. [Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Get in
WaitForNotifications.
TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.StatusChangedEventArgs
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Connection opened.
TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.EventArgs.StatusChangedEventArgs
[Server: . Database: SqlDependencyTest]Executing WAITFOR command..
```

Comment: Where is the database located?  Is it on the PC at work and you are remotely connecting to the data at work from home?

Comment: It is currently in my laptop , where I login with Windows Credentials (given by the company.)

Comment: Is the GUID registry correct?  The Appication Assembly property must match the code.

Comment: I didn't get your point..Can you elaborate it further?

Comment: Is the GUID  the GUID on the work computer or home computer? 13e195b2-0803-4f68-b30f-9dd9fb33546a

Comment: In my home network : it is :{E5D8A564-F6C0-11d2-B35E-00105A1F8569}